# Установка одного и того же Android-приложения из разных источников

Tags: android, kotlin, build, apk

Например, я собрал android-проект и установил его у себя на мобильном устройстве (на одном ПК). Далее, воспользовался другим ПК, добавил код и решил снова установить на своем мобильном устройстве. Но, android studio запрашивает у меня разрешение на то, чтобы удалить похожее приложение и установить текущее. Почему там может происходить? Или же случай, когда мне прислали apk в телеграмме, я скачал его, хочу установить, но оно не устанавливается, выдает сообщение, что приложение не установлено. Это решается так, нужно удалить это приложение с мобильного устройства и заново его установить. Тогда все установится. В чем может быть проблема такого поведения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблем может быть несколько. Вот примерные соображения по описанным случаям:

1. > собрал android-проект и установил его у себя на мобильном устройстве (на одном ПК). Далее, воспользовался другим ПК, добавил код и решил снова установить на своем мобильном устройстве. Но, android studio запрашивает у меня разрешение на то, чтобы удалить похожее приложение и установить текущее.

   Тут проблема в разных дебажных ключах, которыми подписывается приложение. На разных компах при установке студии генерируются разные ключи. Чтобы этой проблемы не было - надо чтобы на всех компах ключ был одинаковый
2. > , когда мне прислали apk в телеграмме, я скачал его, хочу установить, но оно не устанавливается, выдает сообщение, что приложение не установлено

   Тут либо как в первом случае или понижена версия APK или что-то ещё.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что нельзя установить приложение с уже имеющимся именем пакета (android package name) из другого источника.